# Reversing a list through iteration

Tags: python

I am trying to get into Python. Here I am trying to reverse a list through recursion iteration.
I heard of the powerful slicing features but I don't see a chance to use them here:

```
def turn(l):
    skip = 0;
    while(skip < len(l)):
        if(l[skip] < l[skip+1]):
            break
        skip +=1
    t = l[len(l)-1]
    t2 = l[skip]
    l[skip] = t
    l[len(l)-1] = t2

    turn(l) 
    return 0

l = range(0,5)
print turn(l)
```

The code you see above is the current state of experimenting.
But how could I finish the function?

Comment: Can you use the `my_list.reverse()` instead? :)

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Answer (score 5):

If you really need to do it yourself and recursively, what about :

```
def reverse(lst):
    if len(lst) < 2:
        return lst
    else:
        return [lst[-1]] + reverse(lst[:-1])
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the slicing option

```
my_list[::-1]
```

Sorry for being too lazy to analyze your code, but if you really want to reverse list order - you have to stop when you reach the middle of the list.
Here is my solution

```
In [155]: def turn(trgt, offs=0):
    if offs>=len(trgt)/2:
        return
    trgt[offs], trgt[-1-offs] = trgt[-1-offs], trgt[offs]
    turn(trgt, offs+1)
   .....:     

In [156]: 

In [156]: my_list=range(10)

In [157]: turn(my_list)

In [158]: my_list
Out[158]: [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reduce the maximum depth of the stack by splitting the list in half each time instead of pulling one item at a time

```
def rev(L):
    if len(L) < 2:
        return L
    return rev(L[len(L) // 2:]) + rev(L[:len(L) // 2])
```

Comment: The most elegant solution - though a bit too advanced for a beginner

Answer (score 0):

use

```
my_list.reverse()
```

Its easier. An in-built function in python

Comment: I want to do it by hand

Comment: The inbuilt method is faster. So if  you have a user defined function, it will be slow

Answer (score 0):

Here comes the solution:

```
def dreh(list):
    v = list[0] 

    if len(list) > 1: 
        del list[0] 
        dreh(list) 
    else: 
        del list[0] 

    list.append(v)  
    return list

l = range(0,5)
l = dreh(l)
print l
```

But I have to admit though, using the included methods of python is far more convenient :)

Answer (score 0):

I had written this code:

```
li = [0,1,3,5,9,12,14,25,'AAQ',32,54]
print 'li ==',li,'\nid(li) ==',id(li)

def rev(li):
    return [li.pop(-1)]  + rev(li) if li else li

lu =  rev(li)
print 'lu ==',lu,'\nid(lu) ==',id(lu)
print 'li==',li
```

result

```
li == [0, 1, 3, 5, 9, 12, 14, 25, 'AAQ', 32, 54] 
id(li) == 18709560
lu == [54, 32, 'AAQ', 25, 14, 12, 9, 5, 3, 1, 0] 
id(lu) == 18736432
li== []
```

The function `id()` gives the address in memory of an object.
The addresses 18709680 and 18736472 being different, that means that the two identifiers `li` and `lu` are references of two distinct list objects lying at distonct locations in the memory.
It also means that the list object **li** hasn't been reversed in place.
Moreover, after execution the list **li** is empty.

So I wondered if these consequences were acceptable for you.

.

Then I saw your solution in your answering post and I saw it has the same consequences, so you don't worry about them.

Staring at your code, that I wasn't understanding very well at first glance, I realized that it has a similar algorithm as mine, though inversed (!)
I will explain that is the following with the help of a demonstrating evolution of code.

Note that I replaced the identifier `list` with `LIST` because `list` is the name of a builtin class and it is recommended to avoid to overwrite the builtin identifiers.

First , your code is:

```
def dreh(LIST):
    v = LIST[0] 

    if len(LIST) > 1: 
        del LIST[0] 
        dreh(LIST) 
    else: 
        del LIST[0] 

    LIST.append(v)  
    return LIST
```

Examining carefully the following code, you'll easily understand that it does the same as yours, though it does the contrary of yours (!)

```
def dreh(LIST):
    v = LIST[-1] 

    if len(LIST) > 1: 
        del LIST[-1] 
        dreh(LIST) 
    else: 
        del LIST[-1] 

    LIST.insert(0,v)  
    return LIST
```

In your code, the **first** element of the list is removed and kept in object of name `v`, the remaining list is treated again with `dreh()` (the result being that identifier `LIST` then references a new list whose value is the reversed value of initial **LIST** object) and the kept value of **v** is **appended** to this new reversed LIST.

In my code , I do the contrary:
`li.pop(-1)` removes the **last** element of the list, put it alone in a list and **extend** this list of length 1 with the list returned by the recursive function called on the shortened list.

.

---

And now, I will prove that this inversed code is algorithmically the same as my own code.
But before that, a little precision.
In case one passes a void list to your function `dreh()`, that will produce an error because it will begin by trying to remove the first element (or the last in the inversed code) of the void list.
Then your code must be modified a little to hold this case, and it is then :

```
def dreh(LIST):
    if len(LIST)>=1:
        v = LIST[-1] 

    if len(LIST) > 1: 
        del LIST[-1] 
        dreh(LIST) 
    elif len(LIST)==1: 
        del LIST[-1] 

    LIST.insert(0,v)  
    return LIST
```

.

---

And now the evolution of this code that leads to mine. I think the most of the steps are easily understandable. The most tricky step is the one from result `la05` to result `la06`: one must consider it carefully and have a good understanding of the processes implied in the assignements in Python to understand this part. I'm sorry, I can't write all the stuff that would be necessary to explain this step, it would be too long. Anyway, the displaying of results show that the evolution of the code keep the same result all along.

```
li = [0,1,3,5,9,'AAAA',12,14,25,32,105,205]
print 'li  ==',li

def dreh(LIST):
    if len(LIST)>=1:
        v = LIST[-1] 

    if len(LIST) > 1: 
        del LIST[-1] 
        dreh(LIST) 
    elif len(LIST)==1: 
        del LIST[-1] 

    LIST.insert(0,v)  
    return LIST

li = [0,1,3,5,9,'AAAA',12,14,25,32,105,205]
la = dreh(li)
print 'la01==',la

def dreh(LIST):
    #if len(LIST)>=1:
    #    v = LIST[-1]

    if len(LIST) > 1:
        v = LIST[-1] # <======
        del LIST[-1] 
        dreh(LIST)
        LIST.insert(0,v) # <======
    elif len(LIST)==1:
        v = LIST[-1] # <======
        del LIST[-1]
        LIST.insert(0,v) # <======

    #if len(LIST)>=1:
    #    LIST.insert(0,v)
    return LIST

li = [0,1,3,5,9,'AAAA',12,14,25,32,105,205]
la = dreh(li)
print 'la02==',la

def dreh(LIST):
    if len(LIST) > 1:
        v = LIST[-1]
        del LIST[-1] 
        dreh(LIST)
        LIST.insert(0,v)
    elif len(LIST)==1:
        v = LIST[-1]
        del LIST[-1]
        LIST.insert(0,v)

    return LIST

li = [0,1,3,5,9,'AAAA',12,14,25,32,105,205]
la = dreh(li)
print 'la03==',la

def dreh(LIST):
    if len(LIST) > 1:
        #v = LIST[-1]
        #del LIST[-1]
        v = LIST.pop(-1) # <======
        dreh(LIST)
        LIST.insert(0,v)
    elif len(LIST)==1:
        #v = LIST[-1]
        #del LIST[-1]
        v = LIST.pop(-1) # <======
        LIST.insert(0,v)

    return LIST

li = [0,1,3,5,9,'AAAA',12,14,25,32,105,205]
la = dreh(li)
print 'la04==',la

def dreh(LIST):
    if len(LIST) > 1:
        v = LIST.pop(-1)
        dreh(LIST)
        LIST.insert(0,v)
    elif len(LIST)==1:
        v = LIST.pop(-1)
        LIST.insert(0,v)

    return LIST

li = [0,1,3,5,9,'AAAA',12,14,25,32,105,205]
la = dreh(li)
print 'la05==',la

def dreh(LIST):
    if len(LIST) > 1:
        LIST[:] = [LIST.pop(-1)] + dreh(LIST)
    elif len(LIST)==1:
        LIST[:] = [LIST.pop(-1)]

    return LIST

li = [0,1,3,5,9,'AAAA',12,14,25,32,105,205]
la = dreh(li)
print 'la06==',la

def dreh(LIST):
    if len(LIST) > 1:
        LIST[:] = [LIST.pop(-1)] + dreh(LIST)
        return LIST
    elif len(LIST)==1:
        LIST[:] = [LIST.pop(-1)]
        return LIST

li = [0,1,3,5,9,'AAAA',12,14,25,32,105,205]
la = dreh(li)
print 'la07==',la

def dreh(LIST):
    if len(LIST) > 1:
        return [LIST.pop(-1)] + dreh(LIST)
    elif len(LIST)==1:
        return [LIST.pop(-1)]

li = [0,1,3,5,9,'AAAA',12,14,25,32,105,205]
la = dreh(li)
print 'la08==',la

def dreh(LIST):
    if len(LIST) > 1:
        return [LIST.pop(-1)] + dreh(LIST)
    elif len(LIST)==1:
        return [LIST.pop(-1)] + []

li = [0,1,3,5,9,'AAAA',12,14,25,32,105,205]
la = dreh(li)
print 'la09==',la

def dreh(LIST):
    if len(LIST) > 1:
        return [LIST.pop(-1)] + dreh(LIST)
    elif len(LIST)==1:
        return [LIST.pop(-1)] + []
    elif len(LIST)==0:
        return []

li = [0,1,3,5,9,'AAAA',12,14,25,32,105,205]
la = dreh(li)
print 'la10==',la

def dreh(LIST):
    if len(LIST) > 1:
        return [LIST.pop(-1)] + dreh(LIST)
    elif len(LIST)==1:
        return [LIST.pop(-1)] + []
    elif len(LIST)==0:
        return LIST

li = [0,1,3,5,9,'AAAA',12,14,25,32,105,205]
la = dreh(li)
print 'la11==',la

def dreh(LIST):
    if len(LIST) > 1:
        return [LIST.pop(-1)] + dreh(LIST)
    elif len(LIST)==1:
        return [LIST.pop(-1)] + dreh(LIST)
    elif len(LIST)==0:
        return LIST

li = [0,1,3,5,9,'AAAA',12,14,25,32,105,205]
la = dreh(li)
print 'la12==',la

def dreh(LIST):
    if len(LIST) >= 1:
        return [LIST.pop(-1)] + dreh(LIST)
    elif len(LIST)==0:
        return LIST

li = [0,1,3,5,9,'AAAA',12,14,25,32,105,205]
la = dreh(li)
print 'la13==',la

def dreh(LIST):
    if LIST:
        return [LIST.pop(-1)] + dreh(LIST)
    else:
        return LIST

li = [0,1,3,5,9,'AAAA',12,14,25,32,105,205]
la = dreh(li)
print 'la14==',la
```

result

```
li  == [0, 1, 3, 5, 9, 'AAAA', 12, 14, 25, 32, 105, 205]
la01== [205, 105, 32, 25, 14, 12, 'AAAA', 9, 5, 3, 1, 0]
la02== [205, 105, 32, 25, 14, 12, 'AAAA', 9, 5, 3, 1, 0]
la03== [205, 105, 32, 25, 14, 12, 'AAAA', 9, 5, 3, 1, 0]
la04== [205, 105, 32, 25, 14, 12, 'AAAA', 9, 5, 3, 1, 0]
la05== [205, 105, 32, 25, 14, 12, 'AAAA', 9, 5, 3, 1, 0]
la06== [205, 105, 32, 25, 14, 12, 'AAAA', 9, 5, 3, 1, 0]
la07== [205, 105, 32, 25, 14, 12, 'AAAA', 9, 5, 3, 1, 0]
la08== [205, 105, 32, 25, 14, 12, 'AAAA', 9, 5, 3, 1, 0]
la09== [205, 105, 32, 25, 14, 12, 'AAAA', 9, 5, 3, 1, 0]
la10== [205, 105, 32, 25, 14, 12, 'AAAA', 9, 5, 3, 1, 0]
la11== [205, 105, 32, 25, 14, 12, 'AAAA', 9, 5, 3, 1, 0]
la12== [205, 105, 32, 25, 14, 12, 'AAAA', 9, 5, 3, 1, 0]
la13== [205, 105, 32, 25, 14, 12, 'AAAA', 9, 5, 3, 1, 0]
la14== [205, 105, 32, 25, 14, 12, 'AAAA', 9, 5, 3, 1, 0]
```

.

I find this example interesting because it shows that Python offers a great ease to modify a code:
1/ its readability allows to understand what modification can be done
2/ the fact it is a compact langage, easy to rewrite, makes it possible to modify it rapidly.

I don't see how the same could be done as much easily as with C++ for example.